# Websphere multiple instances of same application

Tags: websphere

I wanted to run the same application for different environments in single app websphere server . Can anyone have steps please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is part of a network deployment installation of WebSphere you can set an edition name when you install the application through the admin console or wsadmin. Then it will be managed by the editions manager. So you install the same app multiple times with the same name but different editions and each edition can have a different ear, can have different resources and shared libraries and so on.

[This page in the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwve_xappedcon.html) discusses the editions feature so you can see if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also override the context root of the application at deploy time, using either wsadmin scripting or the admin console, so you could have /appfortest /appforload /appforprod, etc. Even if it's the same ear deployed multiple times, Websphere will treat them as different apps at different context roots.